# db is malformed when i copy and unzip from assets

Tags: android, sqlite, malformed

**I have been troubled by this problem for a long time. i also have android_metadata in my db file.

First, i copy and unzip the db from assets, there is no error here. but when i checkDBValid, the error occur. Not on all devices. only a few devices.**

*here is my code:*

```
private void copyAndUnzipDB() {
        File dbFile;
        if (checkInnerAvailable()){
            dbFile = getDbFileInInnerStorage();
        }else if (checkSDSpaceAvailable()){
            dbFile = getDbFileInSDCard();
        }else {
            throw new NoFreeSpaceException("no free space");
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_ZIP_NAME);;
            ZipInputStream  zis = AssetUtil.getFileFromZip(is);
            if (zis == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Archive is missing a SQLite database file");
            }
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
            IOUtils.copy(zis, fos);
            fos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("unzip failed", e);
        }finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        }

        checkDbValid(dbFilePath);
    }

    private static boolean checkDbValid(String dbPath){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, new DatabaseErrorHandler(){

                        @Override
                        public void onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase dbObj) {
                            isValid = false;
                        }
                    });
            cursor = checkDB.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master", null);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 2){
                isValid = true;
                return isValid;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // database doesn't exist yet.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
            }
            DBTools.closeDatabaseQuietly(checkDB);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

*error log is here:*

```
09-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 E SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 57173 of [b3bb660af9]
4109-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 E SQLiteLog: (11) database disk image is malformed
4209-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 W System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11): , while compiling: select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master
4309-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 W System.err: #################################################################
4409-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 W System.err: Error Code : 11 (SQLITE_CORRUPT)
4509-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 W System.err: Caused By : The database disk image is malformed.
4609-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 W System.err: (database disk image is malformed (code 11): , while compiling: select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master)
4709-21 23:09:49.294 26017 26109 W System.err: #################################################################
4809-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
4909-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
5009-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
5109-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
5209-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
5309-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
5409-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
5509-21 23:09:49.304 26017 26109 W System.err: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1454)
```

Comment: Use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) instead.

Comment: Almost the same as the SQLiteAssetHelper.